Determine the limit distribution of a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z_+}$
Question:Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $Q$ be the transition matrix on $E=\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ defined by
$$Q(i,j)=\binom Nj\left(\frac iN\right)^j\left(1-\frac iN\right)^{N-j},\quad\forall i,j\in\{0,1,\ldots,N\}.$$
In other words, $Q(i,\cdot)$ is the binomial $\mathcal{B}(N,i/N)$ distribution.
Let $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ and let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ be a Markov chain with transition matrix $Q$ started at $X_0=k$.

Verify that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a martingale, which
converges to a limit $X_\infty$, a.s. $n\to\infty.$Determine the law
of $X_\infty$.

My try:I was able to verify that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a martingale but find it hard to determine the law of $X_\infty$,
$\forall j\in E=\{0,1..N\}$,I try to compute:$$\begin{align}&
\mathbb P(X_n=j)=Q^n(k,j)=\sum_{k_2,..,k_{n}\in E}Q(k,k_2)Q(k_2,k_3)..Q(k_{n},j)\\&=\sum_{k_2,..,k_{n}\in E}\binom N{k_2}\left(\frac kN\right)^{k_2}\left(1-\frac kN\right)^{N-k_2}..\binom N{j}\left(\frac {k_n}N\right)^j\left(1-\frac {k_{n}}N\right)^{N-j}
\end{align}$$The sum above seems hard to simplify.
Maybe we should find another method,but I am stuck at finding a better way to determine the law of $X_\infty$.
Edit:I find that $$\mathbb E[r^{X_{n+1}}\mid X_n]=\sum_{j=0}^Nr^jQ(X_n,j)=(1-\frac{X_n}{N}+\frac{X_n}{N}r)^N$$Since the generating function of the binomial $\mathcal{B}(N,X_n/N)$ distribution is $g(r)=(1-\frac{X_n}{N}+\frac{X_nr}{N})^N$.Does it help?

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p344 as an exercise


Since this chain has just two absorbing states, $0$ and $N$, the limit will be one of them. And then the martingale property gives that the expectation of $X_\infty$ equals $X_0$ from which you immediately get the distribution.
